# How to find socket raw data between 2 processes on same PC

Tags: linux, sockets

I have 2 processes running on same Linux box, wcich are connected using tcp socket. Is i possible to get information of raw packet data which is being exchanged between the 2 processes?

Comment: Which kind of information? If you mean sniffing traffic, you can use tcpdump.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/) and listen to localhost/loop back.

Answer (score 1):

Use wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/ and listen on localhost and the port number